# Why doesn't my IP change on manual router turn off/on?

Tags: ip, router, ipv6

Basically the title. I remember that when still having IPv4 addresses, my IP changed after the router turn off/on. This doesn't seem to be the case with IPv6. Since there are almost 10^40 addresses when using IPv6, does IP rotation not occur anymore or do I need to change some settings?

Comment: I don't quite get your question. What do you mean by "IP rotation wiped out"?

Comment: I improved my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic IPv4 address allocation is a common strategy for ISPs to reclaim globally routable IP addresses (a.k.a. "public addresses") since they have to few of them to assign them permanently to their customers. In terms of privacy that means that end users are harder to track. But like NAT, which was never meant to be security mechanism, dynamic address allocation is not meant to be a privacy mechanism (in fact, it is not). With IPv6 neither NAT nor dynamic address allocation is required. Thus, the IPv6 prefix you get from your ISP is likely fixed, at least for a while. A priori there's nothing you can do about it.

The ISP may provide a mechanism to let you have a fresh prefix, e.g. German Telekom is said to have such a mechanism to answer privacy concerns regarding static prefixes. However, even if you got dynamic prefixes, your devices will be trackable by the interface identifier. Privacy extensions may come to mind but they are of only modest use: They change only after a fixed period (typically one day) or if the NIC is reconfigured - they don't change on prefix change! (For those who are curious, see [RFC 4941, Section 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4941#section-3.3), item #6: *New temporary addresses MUST be created by appending the interface's **current** randomized interface identifier to the prefix that was received.*) Thus, by suitable chaining your devices are trackable across  prefix and IID changes. In order to break the chain they must change simultaneously, which, given that there is no sync mechanism, would happen only by coincidence with quite small probability.

Comment: Small subquestion. What is interface identifier? I know that each device has a link identified by interface. Is that what you mean? Also, the only one who can track by interface identifier is ISP. Other websites cannot.

Comment: IPv6 addresses have length 128 bits. Ordinary IPv6 addresses are composed of the prefix and the interface identifier. The prefix takes the upper (left) 64 bits while the interface identifier takes the lower (right) 64 bits. This is related to an important IPv6 design feature: subnets are always /64 (further subnetting is not intended). Example: _2001:db8:73e:1c80_:9ee5:381b:8ac7:21d, where the prefix is _in italics_. The prefix contains routing information while the interface identifier, well, identifies interfaces on a link, i.e. within a /64 subnet.

Comment: Sorry, but the IID is trackable by anyone who sees it, and using a globally routable address that means everyone whom you communicate with. Keep in mind that the IP address is not the only item by which one can be reliably tracked. If you seek a high degree of privacy/anonymity, then use proxies or TOR.